# Intellij 14 not adding pom dependencies in Classpath

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, classpath, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm using Intellij 14.0.3.  I have imported some Maven modules which declares dependencies in their pom.xml files.

In the IDE, when I'm opening a class importing an object from that dependencies, the import is shown as "on error" such as any reference to that object in this class.  When I click on the error and type alt + Enter, Intellij ask me to add the dependency from Maven to the Classpath.

Example:

In my pom I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my class I have the following import on error:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
```

When I click alt + enter intellij ask me:

```
Add library Maven: 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1' to classpath
```

Why Intellij does not import Maven dependencies directly in the classpath?
In Settings -> Maven -> Importing, I've checked "Import Maven projects automatically' but it still doesn't import dependencies.  Try to "Make" the project with no success.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I've finally found a solution.

When the project was initially imported my maven settings.XML was not the good one.  I've changed the path of maven settings ones the workspace was imported ans it seems that it doesnt work very well.  Perhaps a bug? ( intellij 14.0.3).

I've deleted m'y workspace, cloned it from git once a gain and imported as a Maven project taking care that Maven Settings were previously set.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete all files in `.m2` folder. Then setup the `setting.xml` file for maven like this.

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

- **id:** The unique identifier for this proxy. This is used to differentiate between proxy elements.
- **active**: true if this proxy is active. This is useful for declaring a set of proxies, but only one may be active at a time.
- **protocol**, host, port: The protocol://host:port of the proxy, seperated into discrete elements.
- **username, password**: These elements appear as a pair denoting the login and password required to authenticate to this proxy server.
- **nonProxyHosts**: This is a list of hosts which should not be proxied. The delimiter of the list is the expected type of the proxy server; the example above is pipe delimited - comma delimited is also common

Then import your maven project, the ide will automatically download the alldependencies

Comment: In my company, we don't have a direct access to the maven repositories and instead, we are using a Nexus server.  So my Maven settings.xml file is configured according to the Nexus server.

Comment: My settings.xml works in Eclipse so it should in Intellij too.  I've correctly referenced the settings.xml in Intellij's Maven configuration too.

Comment: Did you imported the project as a Maven?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the dependencies marked with `<scope>test</test>` and inside the test folder. Once I moved the files to the main folder, IntelliJ wouldn't find them anymore and I had to remove the test scope.